# javascript/ReactJS: Show results from backend in a list

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs

I am sending a GET request on a Node API with a MongoDB server. I am getting the response as JSON in an array of object format. I want to show all those results in a list. Right now i am making a function like this

```js
class VendorDashboard extends React.Component {
    constructor() {
      super();

      this.state = {

        paginationValue: '86',
        title: ""
      }

      this.handleLogout = this.handleLogout.bind(this);
      this.gotoCourse = this.gotoCourse.bind(this);
    }
    componentDidMount() {
        axios.get('/vendor/showcourses') //the api to hit request
          .then((response) => {
            console.log(response);
            let course = [];
            course = response.data.map((courseres) => {
              this.setState({
                title: courseres.title
              });
            })
          });
```

Right now what is happening is it is showing just one result. I want to show all results on that api. How can i do it?

Comment: you are overriding your title state in each iteration.That's why it is showing only last result

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to collect all the server response and set that as an array of data to the state and use this state data to render:

```
class VendorDashboard extends React.Component {
    constructor() {
        super();

        this.state = {
            paginationValue: '86',
            course: []
        }

        this.handleLogout = this.handleLogout.bind(this);
        this.gotoCourse = this.gotoCourse.bind(this);
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        axios.get('/vendor/showcourses') //the api to hit request
            .then((response) => {
                const course = response.data.map((courseres) => ({
                    id: courseres.id,
                    title: courseres.title
                }));

                this.setState({
                    course
                });
            });
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <ul>
                {
                    this.state.course.map((eachCourse) => {
                        return <li key={eachCourse.id}>{eachCourse.title}</li>
                    })
                }
            </ul>
        )
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

This segment here is overriding the title per course.

```
course = response.data.map((courseres) => {
          this.setState({
            title: courseres.title
          });
        })
```

You can keep the state as an array of titles and do;

```
course = response.data.map((courseres) => {
          return courseres.title;
        })

this.setState({titles: course});
```

And then you can repeat on the array of titles in your component.
Like so in the render method;

```
const { titles } = this.state;
return <div>{titles.map((title, index) => <div key={index}>{title}</div>)}</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

In each map iteration you rewrite your piece of state, it is wrong.
Just put courses in your state:

```
        console.log(response);
        this.setState({ courses: response.data });
```

In render method go through your `state.courses`:

```
render(){
  return(
   <div>
    {this.state.courses.map(course => <h2>{course.title}</h2>)}
   </div>
  );
}
```